# Evitar doble llamada a la API

Tags: next.js

Quiero hacer una llamada a la API de Next.js y en esta llamada pueden viajar datos. Las variables `dod` y `doa` se cargan a partir de datos que tengo en un `Context` que se carga con informacion del `localStorage`. Si las fechas fueron seleccionadas por el usuario, se envia a la API la feche en formato string, y si no hay fecha seleccionada se envia `null`.

En la parte funcional de mi componente tengo esto:

```
const doa = settings?.search?.stay?.end ? new Date(settings?.search?.stay?.start).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    year: "numeric",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
  }) : null;
  
  const dod = settings?.search?.stay?.end ? new Date(settings?.search?.stay?.end).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    year: "numeric",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
  }) : null;


const url = id ? `/api/search/${id}/info?doa=${doa}&dod=${dod}` : null;

if (url) {
    dataFetcher = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data?.data?.results);
  }

  const {
    data: apiResults,
  } = useSWR(url, dataFetcher, {
    revalidateIfStale: false,
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
    revalidateOnReconnect: false,
  });
```

Mi problema es al momento de que mi componente se monta, si el usuario seleccionó fechas previamente, estas comienzan en null y luego de un tiempo se cargan correctamente desde el localstorage.
Entonces la llamada a la API se hace dos veces.

Cabe aclarar que ambas llamadas son válidas, el usuario puede limpiar las fechas y estas viajarian en null, y ambas pueden traer resultados. El problema es que al montarse la llamada se duplica.

Tengo alguna forma de evitar esta doble llamada?

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de las llamadas dobles en el navegador?

Comment: @RichardUrquizaSantiesteban no entiendo, disculpame. Estas llamadas puedo consolearlas en node, las veo en vscode. En la pestaña Network de mi navegador no las encuentro.

Comment: Podrías poner la info de tu `context`? como  está en el `return` y como está definido

Comment: Tu problema no es reproducible, ya que no éste no se encuentra en el fetch (que es el código que colocaste). Se encuentra en quien llama al fetch y cuando lo debe hacer.

Comment: @Yussef quien llama al fetch? useSWR. Cuando debe hacerlo? Si controlaria esto no hubiera escrito la pregunta. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Estimado, yo he copiado su código y no tiene problema alguno. Tú dices que el usuario seleccionó fechas, donde está eso?? porque claramente tu problema no está en el useSWR si lo tienes todo en false, hablas del localstorage pero no hay código de esto tampoco.

Comment: Asumiendo que tengas una interfaz de tipo gráfica, en html, me imagino lo siguiente. El usuario abre el navegador. Se manda una petición en null. Se carga la primera función del componente o pagina que el usuario cargo y este a su vez, rellena los campos de fechas. Se manda la 2da petición. Termina el proces de "carga" de la página. ¿Puedes validar que esto sea lo que está pasando?